# Is it possible to abort calls in android studio without using the permission of PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS? If yes then HOW?

Tags: java, android, permissions

I am working on an application which has following requirements:

when user dial a international number(+92584711587) from the phone dial pad, call has to terminate and open the application with the number on the screen (you can use receivers or services or broadcast receivers).. You can't use permission process_outgoing_calls in the manifest.

Comment: you just need to use setResultData(null); to terminate call .@Sohaib Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

Determining the outgoing call number is done  using broadcast receiver, but managing calls requires you a permission in the manifest.
After you receive the event inside the broadcast receiver, you can easily terminate the call inside the `onReceive` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand we would have to require a permission in manifest to manage calls, but is there any alternative permission for process_outgoing_calls which does the same work, or any alternative code that would perform same function as this process_outgoing_calls.